# Informatica: If Current month data missing, use previous month

Tags: oracle, informatica

The project I'm working on has monthly data for gas prices in California.  The data is taken from a website and loaded into a table.  I've done this part - the data is current until March 2016.  We are now in April, which does not have any data yet, so the next step I need to do is use March's data and place that into April.

Here is what my table looks like right now:

[image: gas_prices]

My question is:  How do I add a new row with first column data of 201604 and use March's price?

Let me know if I need to add more information.

Comment: Do you need to dynamically generate new rows for the missing months, for example, if two months are missing, two rows will be generated? Or, do you always need to insert the latest month's data with previous month's price?

Comment: Yes, I will need to generate a new row.  For example, we are now in April, but there is no information yet.  So I will need to generate a row for April, but use March's data.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO GAS_PRICES(YYYYMM, GAS_PRICE) VALUES (201604, 2.68);
Commit;
```

I can't help but thinking that your table structure is going to hurt later.

- You don't appear to have a primary key which helps with integrity and performance.
- YYYYMM could be a key but it's not clear whether you are storing it as a number or a string.
- The use of YYYYMM as a column name might prove troublesome as that is part of the Oracle data format.
- your naming convention of GAS_PRICES table and GAS_PRICE column could provide confusion due the similarity

Comment: Thanks for your response.  How would I enter that INSERT INTO statement using Informatica?  Is there a way to automate this?  Like, if I didn't know what March's price was, is there a way for Informatica to look at this information and insert it into the table automatically?  And also add the row with the date 201604?  Sorry I'm not very clear.

Comment: @FTA Help me out on this. What is the business requirement for this? Do you need this done once a month, every month?  How often is the data inserted?  Is it ever updated?